# Typescript: Object.assign - shallow or deep copy for delete

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, deep-copy

I have an object with a structure like `data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments`  with

```
...
lstAnnotation?: AnnotationInterface;
...
export interface AnnotationInterface {
  lstComments: CommentList;
}
export class CommentList {
  [key: string]: CommentEntity;
}
...
```

To my understanding the function `Object.assign()` makes a shallow copy. Which means that the content is not copied and the references are maintained. I have a function like

```
Object.keys(this.data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments).map((key: string) => {
      const newEntity = {...this.data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments[key]};
      delete newEntity.cur; // <<<<----------------- [1]
      if (newEntity.add && newEntity.add.trim().length === 0) {
        delete newEntity.add;  // <<<<-------------- [2]
      }
      return JSON.stringify(newEntity);
    }).join();
```

which makes a nice string. To my understanding I create a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/325868) of the content and then remove (`delete`) properties. My question is, why is the `delete` not applied to the original list (`data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments`)?

I have still in `data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments` entries with the `key` `cur`, e.g. `data.edit.lstAnnotation.lstComments['abc'].cur` ==> `object....`

I'm quite happy with the current situation. But if I delete from the copied object and the orginal isn't updated I would say this is a deep copy. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: Your code doesn't call `Object.assign` anywhere... is this a mistake? If you expect that changing the copy by deleting a property should also change the original, it's not clear what behaviour you think should be different to simply not making a copy at all. How do you intend for `const copy = {...original};` to differ in behaviour from `const copy = original;`?

Comment: I think `{...original}` is the same as `Object.assign{{},original}` although I'm not perfectly sure. Especially since there is a time penalty for the later one.

Comment: [Object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is not exactly equivalent to `Object.assign`, because it [doesn't trigger setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), whereas `Object.assign` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code which demonstrates the core issue:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
const original = {a: array, b: 4};
const copy = {};
Object.assign(copy, original);
delete copy.a;
```

What happens:

- An array containing 1, 2, 3 is created, and `array` holds a reference to it.
- An object is created with the property `a` holding a reference to the array, and the property `b` holding the value 4, and `original` holds a reference to the new object.
- An object is created with no properties, and `copy` holds a reference to it.
- `Object.assign` makes a shallow copy of the object `original` refers to, into the object `copy` refers to. This is a shallow copy, so `copy.a` is now a reference to the same array that `original.a` is a reference to; no copy of the array is made.
- The `a` property belonging to the object that `copy` refers to is deleted, so that object no longer has a property named `a`. The object `original` refers to still has its own property named `a`, because it is a different object.

It may help you to understand by [stepping through the execution using the excellent Javascript Tutor tool](http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=const%20array%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%3B%0Aconst%20original%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20array,%20b%3A%204%7D%3B%0Aconst%20copy%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0AObject.assign%28copy,%20original%29%3B%0Adelete%20copy.a%3B&curInstr=0&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D), which shows visually what happens to the program state as each line is executed.

Comment: Yeah, I think I now understand the difference. Thx a lot. Especially the Javascript Tutor is really excellent.